# linq to sql how to join on multiple columns and some condition

Tags: linq

```
var recordhoursQuery = from  w in crnnsupContext.WorkHoursHistories
                               join p in crnnsupContext.ProvStates on w.Province equals p.ProvinceStateID
                               join r in crnnsupContext.Renewals on new {w.WorkYear+1,w.RegNumber} equals new{r.RenewalYear, r.RegNumber}
                               where r.RegNumber == _username
                               select new CRecordHours
                               {
                                   WorkHoursHistory = w,
                                   Renewal = r
                               };
```

How to implement a+1 equals b? Even when i remove `+1`, error still came said "The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect...."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're receiving that error because your anonymous types are different. For `WorkHoursHistories` you're using `WorkYear`, but for `Renewals` you're using `RenewalYear`. For both, `RegNumber` is the same, so it doesn't need to be given a new name.

To fix this change your anonymous types to this:

```
new { Year = w.WorkYear + 1, w.RegNumber } equals
new { Year = r.RenewalYear, r.RegNumber }
```

Normally you could change one of the types to ensure the names are identical, but in your case `Year` is clearer. Also, if you omit assigning a name to `w.WorkYear + 1` you would get an error.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
from  w in crnnsupContext.WorkHoursHistories
join p in crnnsupContext.ProvStates on w.Province equals p.ProvinceStateID
from r in crnnsupContext.Renewals
          .Where(a=>a.RegNumber==w.RegNumber && (w.WorkYear+1)==r.RenewalYear)
where r.RegNumber == _username
select new CRecordHours
{
    WorkHoursHistory = w,
    Renewal = r
    };
```